# How to set up a environment for python application development in Docker Desktop

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, opencv

I am following this [guide](https://hackernoon.com/building-a-facial-recognition-pipeline-with-deep-learning-in-tensorflow-66e7645015b8) to build an environment to develop an facial recognition project in.
I've pulled the image provided in the guide as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsqUh.jpg) using the command
`docker pull colemurray/medium-facenet-tutorial` in the Desktop Docker.
I am running a container with the image but I do not understand how I can develop an application in it (e.g having access to the modules downloaded in Docker)
The only action I think I can take here is opening the CLI of the container as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eINFR.jpg) but I can't find any guide to use it to add the local folder into the environment.

I understand that using anaconda, I'll just have to activate a environment and run jupyter notebook to develop in that environment and I am trying to do the exact same thing with Docker, but I fail make the same connection, any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you just use an ordinary Python virtual environment, even if you're going to eventually deploy into Docker?  If Docker is a target, Anaconda is a little harder to set up than other frameworks like Pipenv or setuptools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three options here:

1. Keep the `Dockerfile` in your workdirectory and adding a copy command in `Dockerfile` that will copy your python files inside docker container. So at the build time your container is built with with the files in it.

```
ADD $PWD/requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r /requirements.txt 
ADD $PWD/ /   #This will add all your workdirectory files in container
```

After that you can access it through `docker run`.

2. You can use `docker cp` command to copy your files in running docker container and then access it using bash.

   https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/
3. You can mount your workdirectory using `-v` flag while running to access whole workdirectory inside container and then run using bash.

`docker run -it -v /path-to-your-wd:/ colemurray/medium-facenet-tutorial`
This will bind your workdirectory at `/` location inside docker container.